# Summing two arrays by element, issue with carrying the 1

Tags: java

So I've gotten these two arrays to add properly when there is no need to carry anything. so a[0,1,1] + b[0,1,1] will give me c[0,0,2,2], but if I similarly do a[0,9,9] + b[0,9,9] I only get c[0, 0, 8, 8]. The loop in method addBigInts doesn't seem to work the way I thought it would. Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AddBigInts {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    //init firstNum array
    int[] firstNum = new int[getDigit()];
    System.out.println("First number:");
    //gets input to pop array
    firstNum = getInt(firstNum);
    //second array is same length
    int[] secondNum = new int[firstNum.length];
    System.out.println("Second number:");
    //pop second array
    secondNum = getInt(secondNum);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstNum));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondNum));
    addBigInts(firstNum, secondNum);
}

//creates array that is one place bigger than entered #
public static int getDigit (){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many digits? ");
    int arraySize = console.nextInt();
    return arraySize + 1;
}

//populates array
public static int[] getInt (int[] num){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=num.length-1; i>0; i--){
        System.out.print("Digit " + i + ": ");
        num[i] = console.nextInt();
    }
    return num;

}

//adds both arrays by index into the sum array
public static int[] addBigInts (int[]numArray1, int[] numArray2){
    int count = Math.max(numArray1.length, numArray2.length);
    int[] sum = new int[count+1];
    //starting at numArray1 & 2 index, sums ints
    for (int i=count-1; i>=0; i--){
        //sum has to be +1 for numArray1 & 2 indexes
        sum[i+1] = numArray1[i] + numArray2[i];
        if (sum[i+1]>9){
            //this line below doesn't seem to execute
            sum[i]++;
            sum[i+1] = sum[i+1] - 10;
        }
        else;

        }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
    return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: First, please note that your code is exception prone if the two operand arrays are not of same length. IF the two lengths differ, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at this line: `sum[i+1] = numArray1[i] + numArray2[i];`

Comment: @D_C: +1 for posting compilable source and a clear description of the problem.

Comment: I spotted your problem, the loop is going in the wrong direction so you are overwriting your previous result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
sum[i+1] = numArray1[i] + numArray2[i];
```

You need:

```
sum[i+1] += numArray1[i] + numArray2[i];
```

By assigning instead of adding you are overwriting the carried 1 from the previous digit.

Answer (score 0):

In your add bigints function, try change store the addition into a temp variable and use that in the if statement

`int temp = numArray1[i] + numArray2[i]
if( temp > 9)`

Comment: This would just add an unnecessary step because I want the sum array